# change the color of the cursor in code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension for vs code which has certain modes, and i wanted to change cursor color (the caret not the mouse cursor) at certain conditions met in my code.

I also am aware that i can use the status bar item (which i've already updated), however i feel that changing the color of the cursor which is where your eye is already focused would be a better indicator that you're in a certain mode.

Is there a way for me to change it in code? So far from what i have searched, i only see it being changed through the settings.json. Any help/nudge towards the right direction to getting this accomplished would be appreciated!

Comment: did you take a look at the docs? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: @LordDraagon - yup i did. this shows how to modify the settings.json by creating a user/workspace setting, which i don't want exactly. what i want to happen is that when i create my custom command, on invoke of it, my caret/cursor will change color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure it out for my own. I'm posting the answer in case somebody else would need it in the future:

```
const configuration = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('workbench'); 
//get settings for workbench where colorCustomizations is present

configuration.update('colorCustomizations', {"editorCursor.foreground": "#FF0000"}, true);
//true will make it apply to global settings (your user settings.json)
```

if you want to get back your old cursor color you have two ways of doing it

1)

```
configuration.update('colorCustomizations', {"editorCursor.foreground": undefined}, true);
//this deletes the colorCustomizations setting on your user settings
```

2)

```
const CURSOR_FOREGROUND = new vscode.ThemeColor('editorCursor.foreground');
//make a backup of the current color in your theme
configuration.update('colorCustomizations', {"editorCursor.foreground": CURSOR_FOREGROUND},true);
```

Hope that helps somebody out. took me a days of searching and experimentation until i arrived at this answer. :)