# Unable to write to Workspace Settings because .. is not a registered configuration

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to update StatusBar color in VScode Setting.json using the Configuration and Workspace. But when the code tries to update I am getting following error:

```
Error: Unable to write to Workspace Settings because workbench.colorCustomizations.statusBar.background is not a registered configuration.
```

here is my code:

```
const conf = workspace.getConfiguration("workbench.colorCustomizations");
console.log('config-->'+JSON.stringify(conf));
await conf.update( "statusBar.background", "#00AA00");
```

On GetConfiguration I am getting the existing StatusBar color value but not able to Update it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50340493/836330  for how to update a setting which is an object, like `colorCustomiztions`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is defaulting to workspace. You can specify global if you want to update it even though you haven't opened a workspace.

Without specifying the target, it will probably do this:

```
await conf.update("statusBar.background", "#00AA00", vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Workspace);
```

You may want to do this:

```
await conf.update("statusBar.background", "#00AA00", vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem relevant to the question.